# How to map objects of getter setter class?

Tags: java, android

I am using GSON to map JSON in getter setter classes. It is working. However, to achieve a functionality, i have to create separate Getter Setter Classes with the same variable but different class name.

```
public class ABC{

    private int totalUsers;

    public int getTotalUsers() {
        return totalUsers;
    }
    public void setTotalUsers(int totalUsers) {
        this.totalUsers = totalUsers;
    }
}
```

Second Class :-

```
public class DEF{

    private int totalUsers;

    public int getTotalUsers() {
        return totalUsers;
    }
    public void setTotalUsers(int totalUsers) {
        this.totalUsers = totalUsers;
    }
}
```

Now the functionality required force me to save values in the second class from the first class. For that i have to do :-

```
def.setTotalUsers(abc.getTotalUsers); // def and abc are objects of their classes
```

Similary, if there are many variable i have to do the same for them also which is very tedious.

**Is there any way that somehow i equate the objects of the two classes and their values get copied automatically ?**

Comment: ABC <-> JSON <-> DEF?

Answer (score 1):

I think, you would like to use different classes with the same value. There is no true solution but there are possible ways.

Example : [Copy constructors](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=12)

```
public class ABC{
    public ABC(DEF def) {
      // here copy the date form def
    }
}

public class DEF{
    public DEF(ABC abc) {
      // here copy the date form abc
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Making `ABC` the parent class of `DEF` will do the trick. If it works for your implementation.

Answer (score 0):

If it is okay to use third party libraries, Then try these..

[BeanUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils/apidocs/org/apache/commons/beanutils/BeanUtils.html) from **Apache Commons** by using **copyProperties(Object, Object)** method.

[Dozer](http://dozer.sourceforge.net/documentation/gettingstarted.html) is good for bean conversations.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be a tool which can finish the object property copy.the code like this.

```
//This sentence should be finish the properties copy,it could copy the source properties
// to the dest properties but you should get an jar 
BeanUtils.copyProperties(java.lang.Object dest,java.lang.Object source);
// You can get the tool of BeanUtils by this Url
http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils/
```